# Test Report Framework for documenting steps in code with protractor jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, test-reporting

As a Test Automation guy, I would like to document the test steps, expected result and actual result in the code itself.
When the test is run, the Test Automation code itself makes the test results as well as the test case design in such a way so that we do not need to write the test case/test design in a separate tool like QC or maintain other word documents etc. and put extra effort.

In my earlier project, the ExtentReports framework for Selenium with Java was very handy for doing this, however I have not been able to find a similar tool for Protractor, Jasmine, Javascript combination.

I hope I was clear in my query.

Comment: So you want sort of logs and reports ?
Have you seen how jasmine validates through `expect` statements?

Comment: You can try using Cucumber with protractor and use https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter for reporting need

Comment: @Kishan Yes I know the expect statements. I dont want the logs. I want to put the test case documentation in the code itself and have the code produce the "Test Case documentation" when it has executed along with the test report. Barney:  We are using Jasmine and not cucumber and do not have the flexibility to use Cucumber now as we already have a lot of test cases.

Comment: @Win : You can generate the reports in an html format using `Jasmine Allure Reporter`.

Comment: @Kishan thanks. I will try to test it but it seems that it just makes the test report. I want to generate the test case based on those test steps that I will put in the test case itself.